# how to split a string in c++ with Qtcreator

Tags: c++

i write this program to split string in QtCreator

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
string s("Somewhere down the road");
istringstream iss(s);

do
{
    string sub;
    iss >> sub;
    cout << "Substring: " << sub << endl;
} while (iss);

return 0;
}
```

but it returns this error

```
main.cpp:23:24: error: variable ‘std::istringstream iss’ has initializer but incomplete type
```

why? what have i do ?
is there any other easy ways ?

thanks

Comment: This question is not Qt-related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `<sstream>` header for string streams.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QT, why not use the convenience functions included in the library for QString objects such as:

```
QString::section()
QString::left()
QString::right()
```

or for checking:

```
QString::contains()
```

It would save you from writing your own code to do this.